# How to finish a specific activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I know you might think that this question have been asked a lot, but I've been looking into different cases, all cases they just want to close all activities when logged out. Here is my scenario:

1) Start the app with Splash Screen then I used finish()
//I set this activity as MAIN so it's first to open - that is why I cannot setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) because it basically goes back to MAIN

2) Introduction Pager(4 sliding pages) with Login and Signup buttons

3) Login and signup buttons direct you to corresponding activities
// I didn't use finish in introduction pages because I want the user to have the ability to go back to introduction if for example pressed signup by mistake

4) after performing login/signup the user will be directed to the homepage(Here I used finish to kill login/signup activities because I won't need them anymore)

So all previous activities are now finished except for the introduction pager, when the user press back the app will finish homepage and go back to introduction, but I don't want that! I just want the app to quit, I don't want the introduction pager to be running on the background. How do I finish introduction pager when onCreate method is called in homepage?

I have another related question I didn't want to post another thread for it: how to get the previous activity? like I don't want to use the action bar to navigate, I created a button (<- Back) and when I press it I want to bring the previous activity, how do I get the previous activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make your IntroductionActivity a single istance in the manifest like this: `launchMode = "singleInstance"`

There are many ways you can do this, the fastest, I guess, is to use a static field that refers to that activity. Add  this in your IntroductionActivity:

```
public static Activity mActivity;

onCreate(){
  this.mActivity = this;
}
```

Then when you reach the homepage you can do this:

```
onCreate(){
  IntroductionActivity.mActivity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but the transition animation have been changed when I used singleInstance launchmode, any reason why? any idea how to get it back to normal?

Comment: @YousifAl-Raheem Can you be more specif? What is the animation you want, and when you want it to run?

Comment: when you don't set Launch Mode to anything then it's by default will be equal to standard, which have the normal transition(fade in), but when I used your method and set the Introduction pager to Single Instance, the transition have been changed with it (whenever I access or leave the introduction pager), now it's more like sliding in from the top. I don't want to have more than one transition mode.

Comment: You are holding a static reference to an activity. This will never go away unless you clear it manually from somewhere -> you are creating a memory leak!

Comment: @Aimen7 When you finish the activity the reference is deleted, so GC should clean it. Am I wrong?

Comment: My concern with this answer approach is as Leebedeev described, you may be causing a memory leak by guarding a reference to an activity, that could be potentially dangerous

Answer (score 0):

Use finish(); after you start the next activity

Example:

```
Intent itr=new Intent("com.example.splash.Second");
startActivity(itr);
finish();
```